# How to secure spring boot microservices having identity provider for authentication in a stateless manner?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

How to implement security on spring-boot microservices integrated with angular UI. I have an external identity provider(Ping Federate) to support SSO and all user roles/authorities are maintained in the application database.

What is the best approach to secure APIs? If Oauth is recommended way, how to implement it(Stateless).

Should the Authorization Server be customized to connect to the
identity provider Authorization Server and generate tokens from the custom Authorization Server?
or would it be better if
Oauth2 client generates token by loading user details from the database after successful authentication with the identity provider?

I have tried to implement custom auth server, which internally connects to identity provider auth server taking reference from
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver

But it is stateful and I am looking for a stateless approach, also how to customize after successful authentication to load user roles/authorities and generated token from application database

Any code samples along with suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is way to broad. The asker is basically asking for a full security oauth2 implementation. Voted to close

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I am not asking for a full implementation just seeking a direction to proceed as per industry standards.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep things simple with regular OpenID setup?

- pingfederate: authorization-server responsible for issuing authorization token holding end-user identity and roles
- angular UI: client
- spring Rest service: resource server with security based on end-user identity and roles from the authorization token

You might not need anything more.

Get a look at this tutorial I wrote: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication

Adapting it to ping federate should be just a matter of setting a few properties:

- issuer URI
- which private claim to get roles from

(but I haven't tried for ping federated yet).

If you happen to need more than just RBAC in resource server (RoleBasedAccessControl => security decisions based on user authorities), you might have a look at this other tutorial too: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication

Edit:
starting form the first tutorial, you could add this:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter(RolesService rolesService) {
        return jwt -> rolesService.getRolesBySubject(jwt.getSubject()).stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class RolesService {

    @Cacheable("user_roles")
    public Set<String> getRolesBySubject(String userSubject) {
        // FIXME: call a JPA repository or remote WebService instead
        return Set.of("MACHIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this one is that user roles are not maintained in ping but in separate database as the application will have different roles for each user. That is why I was looking for customizing the spring auth server

Comment: Maybe you can configure ping to attach roles from that database to access tokens. If ping cant, you could use a more configurable OIDC provider instead (like Keycloak). You could even use Keycloak in front of ping (ping being just an identity provider for your Keycloak instance)

Comment: Last, you could also configure an authentication converter which queries a web-service exposing roles by user subject (or other identifier from authorization-token like email or something). I have a Keycloak mapper which does something aproaching here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api